# Removing full width from flexbox centered div

Tags: css

How does one remove the full width from this flexbox centered div or its child?

Ie. this:

[image]

Should be:

[image]

```css
.main {
    color: white;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
}

.wrapper p {
    color: #000;
    background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>Please press Enter to continue installation</p>
    </div>
    <p>Welcome to Windows 95</p>
</div>
```

Comment: wth are you building??

Comment: @JakeParis Windows 95 apparently.  Although, I think in the interest of old technology, OP should definitely be using tables for layout, and not flexbox.  We gotta support Netscape Navigator man...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `margin: 0 auto` to `p` element inside `.wrapper`:

```css
.main {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
}
.wrapper p {
  color: #000;
  background: lightgrey;
  margin: 0 auto;/*add margin 0 auto*/
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Please press Enter to continue installation</p>
  </div>
  <p>Welcome to Windows 95</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `auto` to the left and right margins of the `<p>` to center it, and specify a width less than 100% to make it not full width .

```css
.main {
    color: white;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
}

.wrapper p {
    color: #000;
    background: lightgrey;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>Please press Enter to continue installation</p>
    </div>
    <p>Welcome to Windows 95</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Seems that max-width isn't really needed, but spot on with the margin. Thanks a lot!